# Restore SQL 2008 database fails with error on page xxx:xxx

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2008, restore

This is the situation:

Got a full backup (.bak file) of a SQL 2008 database, with partitions. The .bak file is 100gb.

I need to restore this database on a different server, to a new database. Command is like this:

```
Restore Database [newname] FROM DISK= N'D:\mydatabase.bak' WITH FILE = 1
MOVE 'mydatabasename' TO 'C:\mydatabase.mdf'
MOVE 'Partition1' TO 'C:\`mydatabase_1.ndf'etc..
STATS = 1
```

After 52 percent processed, I get this error:

```
Msg 3183, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
RESTORE detected an error on page (8481:555819297) in database "dbname" as read from the backup set.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

Before all default suggestions come up, this is what I have already done:

- Checkdb on original database --> no errors
- Restore the .bak file on my local machine --> no errors, so the backup is correct.

What can I do to troubleshoot this? How can I get to the actual problem?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Also asked on stackoverflow, but they suggested to ask it on serverfault:
[Link to stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518275/restore-sql-2008-database-fails-with-error-on-page-xxxxxx)

Comment: Make sure the account under which the MSSQLServer service starts is the member of “Domain User Group” with write accesses for the Windows folders (share folders). see here: http://www.slideshare.net/jason_clark03/sql-server-backup-error-3013-causes-and-resolution

Comment: How did you backup the database? Can you try the backup again with "copy-only"? How about trying a compressed backup instead?

Answer (score 1):

It is unusual to get a read error in a file that you can't reproduce on different hardware, unless the underlying disk/storage system of the faulting server is having problems.

If you ran the restore twice on the server, I presume that it failed both times. Did the error occur on the same page? If not, I'd suspect a hardware problem with the disk and I'd look at that using Performance Monitor to look at the physical sec/transfer values for the disk. If the error occurred at the same page, then I would suspect that file. Is the copy on your local made from the one that fails on the server, or from some other source? Perhaps the .bak was corrupted while copying it from that source to the server.

It would be best to get another copy of the backup file, if possible. If that is not an option, I would run a checkdb on the database that you did manage to (apparently) restore cleanly. If that is clean, I would consider detaching the database from my local machine, copying all of the data and log files to the server and reattaching the database. And then doing another checkdb.

Comment: We had a backup that gave an error on page (0:0). After that i created a new full backup, and copied it to target server. that is the error from my post: page (8481:555819297). Checkdb on the source database gives no errors. Testing restore on other partition now (but same physical disk). Disk transfers/sec is going up and down between 2 and 25 max (think avg is about 6 or 7).